# Let $I,J$ be ring then show that $V(I+J)=V(I) \cap V(J)$

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

$V(I+J)=V(I)\cap V(J)$  ,, ( V states zero set)

I showed one way but the way that I ask you now is a problem for me.

$V(I+J)=\{ P\in A^n: (F+G)(P)=0, \forall F+G \in I+J \}$

$={P\in A^n:F(P)+G(P)=0,∀F+G\in I+J}$ My question is in here.

I thought that to show $V(I)∩V(J)$, $F(P)$ and $G(P)$ must be $0$. Thus, $P∈V(I),V(J)$. Hence $P∈V(I)\cap V(J)$. I have confusion about why can't be $F(P)=2$ and $G(P)=−2$ or suchlike

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't explained your notation (and you mean ideal not ring in the title). So let's clarify things and state that $A$ is a field,  $I$ and $J$ are ideals in $A[x_1, \ldots x_n]$. Then here is a sketch of the proof that $V(I + J) = V(I) \cap V(J)$, where I use $P$ for a variable ranging over $A^n$. I hope you will be able to fill in the details.

1. If $P \in V(I + J)$, then as, $I \subseteq I + J$ and $J \subseteq I + J$, we have that $P \in V(I)$ and $P \in V(J)$, so $P \in V(I) \cap V(J)$. This gives us that $V(I + J) \subseteq V(I) \cap  V(J)$.
2. If $P \in V(I) \cap V(J)$, then $F(P) = G(P) = 0$ whenever $F \in I$ and $G \in J$. But any element of $I + J$ has the form $F + G$ for some $F \in I$ and some $G \in J$, and then we have $(F + G)(P) = 0$. This gives that $V(I) \cap V(J) \subseteq V(I + J)$.

Comment: Okayy.  Is first part related to following if $ I \subset J $ then $V(J) \subset V(I)$

Comment: Yes, you could use that for the first part. Or you can just do it from the definitions.

Comment: I couldn't obtain by using definition. As I wrote in above, $V(I+J)=\{ P\in A^n: (F+G)(P)=0, \forall F+G \in I+J \}$. Moreover, $V(I+J)=\{ P\in A^n: F(P)+G(P)=0, \forall F \in I, G \in J \}$. But I couldn't decide that $F(P)$ and $G(P)$ must be zero.

Comment: The point is that in the second set comprehension, you must have $F(P) + G(P) = 0$ for **every** $F\in I$ and $G\in J$: in particular you must have $F(P) + G(P) = 0$ when $G$ is the zero polynomial and likewise when $F$ is the zero polynomial.

Comment: Okay, I guess I got the ideal now. The condition is satisfied for every ideal. Because of that they must be $0$. Thank you!